# How to use Spring @Retryable as a meta-annotation and support listeners?

Tags: spring-retry

I have a code base with several nearly-identical usages of `@Retryable`, all driven by the same configuration values. So I created a new annotation that's annotated with ("inherits") `@Retryable`, like this:

```java
@Documented
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({ TYPE, METHOD })
@Retryable(
        include = RestClientException.class,
        maxAttempts = 5,
        backoff = @Backoff(delay = 1000, multiplier = 3)
    )
public @interface RESTClientRetry {

    @AliasFor(annotation = Retryable.class, attribute = "listeners")
    String[] listeners() default {};

    @AliasFor(annotation = Retryable.class, attribute = "include")
    Class<? extends Throwable>[] include() default {};

    @AliasFor(annotation = Retryable.class, attribute = "maxAttemptsExpression")
    String maxAttemptsExpression() default "";

    @AliasFor(annotation = Retryable.class, attribute = "backoff")
    Backoff backoff() default @Backoff();
}
```

This works as expected, except for when I want usages of this annotation to use their own listeners. Usage is like this:

```java
@RESTClientRetry(listeners = "retryLoggerBean1")
```

In an application where there are several `RetryListener` beans (named `retryLoggerBean1`, `retryLoggerBean2`, etc), they are *all* getting called for *every* method that's annotated with `RESTClientRetry`, even though each annotation specifies its own `listeners`.

Using the debugger, I see that when `AnnotationAwareRetryOperationsInterceptor` is invoked, the `Retryable` object has an empty value for `listeners`. So it seems like that interceptor is not supporting annotation "inheritance" (composition). Without any annotation-specific listeners, it's falling back to the global set of listeners, which explains why I'm seeing them *all* invoked for *every* method.

Is this a known limitation or bug with the interceptor, or is there another way to wrap `@Retryable` with my own annotation and still le individual usage define which listener to use?

Comment: Duplicated here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry/issues/301

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a limitation of older spring-retry versions (1.2.x), which were written before the `@AliasFor` annotation existed. 1.3.x versions of spring-retry work as expected with the code in the question.

Thus, the solution is to update to a 1.3.x (or later) version of spring-retry.